# JSON Data structure parsing?

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to consume this data via ajax.  Like so:

```
var $data = $.get('/data.js', function(data){
        console.log($(data));
});
```

In the data.js file I have this object:

```
var data = {
    "testData" : {
        "order" : [21,22,33,32,55,20,41],
        "categories" : {
            "41" : {
                "id" : 41,
                "title" : "Foo",
                "count" : 100,
                "href" : "/foo/Foo/"
            },
            "20" : {
                "id" : 20,
                "title" : "Bar",
                "count" : 100,
                "href" : "/foo/Bar/"
            }
        }
    },
    "following" : {
        "order" : [6,5,4,3,1,0],
        "friends" : {
            "0" : {
                "id" : "0",
                "name" : "Friend Name",
                "href" : "/test/link",
                "title" : "Friend Name"
            },
            "1" : {
                "id" : "1",
                "name" : "Friend2 Name",
                "href" : "/test/link2",
                "title" : "Friend2 Name"
            }
        }
    }
};
```

What am I missing here?  Is there a way to consume and parse this data without modifying the actual data source?

Comment: That's not JSON, that is a JavaScript object.

Comment: @Felix, it would more accurate to say "That's not JSON, that's JavaScript".

Comment: @Squeegy: Fair enough ;)

Comment: Absolutely, I understand this is not a JSON object but a JavaScript object, and that was my question. Is it possible to call this like I have and consume it as is.  Thank you guys for the quick responses!!

Answer (score 1):

`data` is JavaScript object sent by response, so I suggest changing the file into JSON and use it like that:

```
$.get('/data.json', function(data){
    // do here what you need to do with returned data or call callback
    console.log(data);
}, 'json');
```

`data.json` file should look like that (basically only the object notation, without assignment etc.):

```
{
    "testData" : {
        "order" : [21,22,33,32,55,20,41],
        "categories" : {
            "41" : {
                "id" : 41,
                "title" : "Foo",
                "count" : 100,
                "href" : "/foo/Foo/"
            },
            "20" : {
                "id" : 20,
                "title" : "Bar",
                "count" : 100,
                "href" : "/foo/Bar/"
            }
        }
    },
    "following" : {
        "order" : [6,5,4,3,1,0],
        "friends" : {
            "0" : {
                "id" : "0",
                "name" : "Friend Name",
                "href" : "/test/link",
                "title" : "Friend Name"
            },
            "1" : {
                "id" : "1",
                "name" : "Friend2 Name",
                "href" : "/test/link2",
                "title" : "Friend2 Name"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Remember that JavaScript is best suited for **event-based programming**. You should probably code your solution using callbacks, because it is sometimes **executed asynchronously** and returns value before actually finishes executing.

Comment: @FelixKling: [`.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) is just a shortcut to [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), which is a shortcut to [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: I know, but it is more expressive and will parse the JSON automatically which might not be the case with `get` if the content type is not correctly set.

Comment: @FelixKling: No, the guess will be based on MIME type (see `dataType` setting on [`.ajax()` documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)). But I have changed my answer so it is explicitly set. Thanks. Let me know if you have any other questions.